# How to debug ServiceBus-triggered Azure Function locally?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

My function will be triggered from an existing ServiceBus topic. I have created the function using the new tooling in VS2017 (15.3) preview, as a compiled function.

How can I test this function locally?

Comment: Press F5 and send a message to your service bus topic

Comment: :-) Yes. I am aware of that possibility. But is there an easy way doing that in the context of the function? That is, reusing settings and maybe do it every time I start debugging?

Comment: If you want it to add messages on startup you could consider adding an additional timer triggered function to your app that will automatically put messages onto the service bus on a short interval to facilitate debugging.

Comment: It's a triggered functions, so when you debug, it's expected that the function will be triggered by an event. In addition to the suggested options, another option is to drop a message on a queue using a tool (SBExplorer, ServiceBus360, Cloud Explorer, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether your function will be triggered by Azure Service Bus messages, you need to own a Azure Subscription and create a Service Bus namespace because Microsoft haven't provided Azure Service Bus emulator like Azure Storage emulator.

If you want to debug your function, you could create a new console application and invoke the function you defined. Steps below are for your reference.

Step 1, Create a Console Application.

Step 2, Add Project reference to the function project.

Step 3, Install Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs -Version 2.1.0-beta1 package from NuGet to your console application.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs -Version 2.1.0-beta1
```

Step 4, Use following code to invoke your function.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Function1.Run("msg1", new MyTraceWriter(TraceLevel.Info));
    }
}

public class MyTraceWriter : TraceWriter
{
    public MyTraceWriter(TraceLevel level) : base(level)
    {

    }

    public override void Trace(TraceEvent traceEvent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(traceEvent.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

For a non-http triggered function, you can send a POST request to the local administrator endpoint. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local)

like this (I am using Postman)
[image]

Comment: Teomat, have you successfully done this for a function triggered by a Service Bus message? I'm trying to do exactly this, and keep getting SerializationException's when my function calls BrokeredMessage#GetBody<string>() to get the body of the message.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Don't serialize it yourself, the runtime will do that for you. Just include your string parameter in the Run function: Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queuename",......)]string Info, TraceWriter log)

Comment: Thanks! I needed to do some additional actions to make it work: 1) to change trigger signature accepting `string msg` instead of `Message msg`; 2) to do JSON escape for my test SB message like `{ "input": "{ \"testobj\": { \"testprop\": \"testval\"} }"`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Saved me a lot of trouble. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan, you don't need to change signature, you can use Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body) to get the data you posted.

Answer (score 3):

You run the project in debug mode and create a JSON payload for the message then you can post a complete json object in this format.

```
{
    "input": "<trigger_input>"
}
```

for example

http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/OrderFunction

[image]

You can then read message in your function body and get the Json you posted.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)
```